# python compilation error

Tags: python, networking

am using Python brisa Framework to implement UpnP protocols. I was trying to make a device but while executing it in ubuntu linux env, it throws me an error.What does thsi eror mean? DO i need to change the framework files??

/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/cptools.py:4: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py:16: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import sha

Comment: DeprecationWarning ... Deprecation *Warning* ... Deprecation **Warning** ...

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, it isn't compiled :)

Comment: @gnur: Yes it is, it just isn't compiled to machine code.

Comment: But it is done at runtime, so you have runtime errors and not compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an error, it's a warning.  You're using code written for python 2.5 or earlier, before there was a hashlib module.

Comment: So, how would I get rid of this warning??

Comment: I changed it to import hashlib but it is still showing me the same error.